# python-igraph crashes when adding an edge between two vertices that have objects for names

Tags: python, igraph

I'm running igraph 0.7.1 in Python 3.4 under Windows 7, and the following code crashes:

```
import igraph

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

alice = Person('Alice')
bob = Person('Bob')
g = igraph.Graph()
g.add_vertex(alice)
g.add_vertex(bob)
print(g.vs[0]['name'] == alice)
print(g.vs[1]['name'] == bob)
g.add_edge(alice, bob)
```

The output is as follows:

```
True
True
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\igraph\__init__.py", line 237, in add_edge
    return self.add_edges([(source, target)])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\igraph\__init__.py", line 255, in add_edges
    return GraphBase.add_edges(self, es)
TypeError: only numbers, vertex names or igraph.Vertex objects can be converted to vertex IDs
```

It seems that this code should work, because alice and bob are vertex names in this case, and are in fact stored in the vertex's 'name' attribute.  Interestingly, the following does not crash:

```
g = igraph.Graph()
g.add_vertex('Alice')
g.add_vertex('Bob')
g.add_edge('Alice', 'Bob')
```

Comment: I realized I should make my question more explicit: does anyone know why this crashes?  Is there some other way to use a Python object for a vertex name instead of a string?

Comment: So, what's your question? Clearly igraph doesn't support using object as vertex's name.

Comment: If igraph doesn't support using objects as vertex names, why would it allow the vertices to be constructed in the first place?

Comment: It's kind of a bug. "name" is just another property of nodes that happened to be used in some other functions. Like other properties it can be anything but meanwhile some other functions may rely on some specific data type.

Comment: In your case you can just use the string as nodes' names and store the objects in another property like g.vs[0]['data'].

Comment: I can, but it will complicate my program.  I'll submit a bug report to the igraph people, thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you use a subclassed str for your object?